# ADAL for .NET for iOS app can authenticate previous user even after logging out

Tags: c#, ios, azure, xamarin, adal

I am using Xamarin to write an iOS app which uses Azure Active Directory as the authentication provider with REST API in the Azure web app. I am using ADAL .NET version 3.5.208012240.
There is a scenario where even after logging out, the previous user may be signed in successfully without needing to enter their password.
When the user chooses to sign out, the app calls
`authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear()` and
`/oauth2/logout`.
On the next attempt to sign in, it calls `AcquireTokenAsync()` again thus:

```
_authResult = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUri, 
ClientId, new Uri(RedirectUrl), platformParam);
```

This displays the normal Microsoft sign-in web page, where there is a link that reads, "Can't access your account?" When the user taps this link, it redirects to a page with title, "Microsoft Online Password Reset", and heading "Can't access your account?" followed by text "Visit passwordreset.microsoftonline.com from your browser to reset your password." There is also a link to go "Back".
When the user taps "Back", it returns from the `AcquireTokenAsync()` with the same token as the previous user who has signed out. When this occurs, the app will proceed as if that user has signed in again successfully.
I understand the server is probably using the browser cookies to do this, but I am not sure how to prevent this scenario where a user signs out, then a different user on the same device can sign in as the previous user without entering the password.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you must delete all cookies stored on `NSHttpCookieStorage`. Do both: ADAL sign out and delete all cookies.